# modify query function in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm learning "Sequelize".
I went through documentation and got this code somewhere else.

```
Model = require('../models/Salesman')
module.exports.creareSalesman = (req, res, next) => {
Model.create(req.body).then(
    result => {
        res.status.json({data: result})
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

but I want this in the below structure,

```
Model = require('../models/Salesman')
module.exports.creareSalesman = (req, res, next) => {
    Model.create(req.body, function (result, err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            res.status.json({data: result})
        }
    });
}
```

I tried this,.it didn't send the response. But inserted the data correctly to db.
How to get the response in this case.?

Comment: The [callback signature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents) is `function(err, result){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Model.create`](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-create) method returns a `Promise`, and does not have a callback parameter.
So you either handle the `Promise` with then:

```
module.exports.creareSalesman = (req, res, next) => {
  Model.create(req.body)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status.json({ data: result });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Or use `async await`:

```
module.exports.creareSalesman = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const result = await Model.create(req.body);
      res.status.json({ data: result });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```